# Question on using mustache partials with couchapp and evently

Tags: couchdb, couchapp

I have been evaluating couchdb for a project and am using couchapp to develop the prototype. So far all I can only say it that it is an awesome tool. I have however run across a problem (which is surely caused by ignorance of the tool) that I cannot seem to get mustache partials to work and the reason for that I believe is that evently can't find the definitions of the partials I am using.

example out of a message queue evently template (evently/queues/_change/mustache.html)

```
<div class="queue">{{>queue_info}}</div>
...
```

and I have a queue_info.html with something like

```
<h2>{{name}}</h2>
```

where do I place the "queue_info.html" so that evently would find it and insert it properly? If I put it in the same directory as mustache.html it doesn't work.

Best regards,
Vukasin

Comment: not sure what comment you are referring to? I didn't know how to get mustache to work for this example so I posted the question. It turned out that I have found a solution before I got an answer so I posted it. Since it was an answer it made little sense to write it as a question. I apologize  if that offends you in some way, you are welcome to flag it.

Comment: kudos for answering your own question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ok i have figured this out so I am writing to help anyone who might run into the same issue in the future:

if you have data:

```
{  "queue_info": { "name": "queuename", "owner": "user1" }, "messages": [...] }
```

and you want to render the "queue_info" part using a partial you will need to create the partial called "queue_info" (it is important that the partial is called the same as the field) and place it in a file "queue_info.html" located in the subdirectory "partials" of the evently directory you are working in).

so we have evently/queues/_change/mustache.html

```
<div class="queue">
{{>queue_info}}
{{#messages}}
   <div class="message">
       author: {{author}}
       message: {{text}}
   </div>
{{/messages}}
</div>
```

and evently/queues/_change/partials/queue_info.html

```
Queue: {{name}}
Owner: {{owner}}
```

when we push this couchapp to the server we get a result which cascades as expected.

Hope this helps someone :-)